# How can I test sidekiq-scheduler in my local?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduler, sidekiq

I am trying to add couple of scheduled workers to my rails application. These workers will be crawling different sites in given intervals.

I want to test these workers but not able to do it. I am starting redis and my application. What should I do to see whether my scheduled jobs are working or not?

Here is my crawler class:

```
class AyedasCrawler
include Sidekiq::Worker
```

and my sidekiq.yml is:

```
:schedule:
  ayedas_crawler:
    cron: '0 * * * * *'   # Runs once per minute
    class: AyedasCrawler
```

Comment: you should start the sidekiq too.

Answer (score 2):

- start the sidekiq worker and the scheduler processes by running
  `bundle exec sidekiq` or `sidekiq` from your app root in the command-line.
- sidekiq-scheduler provides an extension to the Sidekiq web interface that adds a Recurring Jobs page.
  There are two ways to do this:

  1. In your routes.rb file, just below the `require 'sidekiq/web'`, add `require 'sidekiq-scheduler/web'`
  2. In your config.ru, just below the `require 'sidekiq/web'`, add

`require 'sidekiq-scheduler/web'
run Sidekiq::Web`

On the browser, goto ==> `http://localhost:{port}/sidekiq/recurring-jobs`. where `{port}` is the port your application is running in.

You will see the list of scheduled jobs for your application and some other details about it.

Read more in the official [documentation](https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Sidekiq process as well.

`bundle exec sidekiq`

It will start both worker/s and the scheduler

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to test it using rspec, you can to the following:

```
it 'spawns scheduled workers' do
  Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file('config/sidekiq.yml')[: schedule]
  Sidekiq::Cron::Job.all.each(&:enque!)
  expect(AyedasCrawler.jobs.size).to be(1)
end
```

It loads the YAML configuration, enqueues all the jobs, and asserts if the job has been enqued.

Using this method you can validate if your schedule YAML is correct. It will **NOT** test CRON syntax and scheduled intervals.

I'm also using https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq to allow sidekiq testing without jobs actually being executed.